# Spark is creating too many threads when reading ML model

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel text classification problem that I tried to resolve using the binary relevance method, by creating one binary classifier per label.
I have to read 10000 models classifier to perform my classification phase, after my training phase, on all my documents, using spark.
But for an unknown reason, it becomes very slow when I try to read more than 1000 models, because spark creates a new thread each time, which progressively slow down the process, and I don't know why.
Here is the minimal code which illustrate my problem.

```
package entrepot.spark;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class maintest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
        try(SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").getOrCreate()) {
            //Listing directories to get the list of labels
            Set<String> labels = new HashSet<>();
            FileStatus[] filesstatus = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration()).listStatus(new Path("C:\\Users\\*\\Desktop\\model\\"));
            for(int i = 0; i < filesstatus.length; i++) {
                if(filesstatus[i].isDirectory()) {
                    labels.add(filesstatus[i].getPath().getName());
                }
            }

            List<MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
            // Here is the problem
            for(String label : labels) {
                System.out.println(label);
                MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel model = MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.load("C:\\Users\\*\\Desktop\\model\\" + label + "\\CL\\");
                models.add(model);
            }

            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the program on Windows, with Spark 2.1.1 and Hadoop 2.7.3, using the following command line:

```
 .\bin\spark-submit^
 --class entrepot.spark.maintest^
 --master local[*]^
  /C:/Users/*/eclipse-workspace/spark/target/spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

To download a small repetitive sample of one of my labels model, here is the link : we.tl/T50s9UffYV (Why can't I post a simple link ??)

PS: Even though the models are serializable, I couldn't save and load everything at once using a java collection and an object stream, because I get a scala conversion error. Instead, I'm using the save/load static method from MLLib on each model, resulting in hundreds of thousands of files.

Comment: I have to ask.. Why this setup?  Multiclass should be way better at this..

Comment: Because it's a multilabel classification problem, not multiclass.

Comment: There is no constraint on how many of the classes the document can be assigned to

Comment: Thinking out loud.. what about using the same approach as in word2vec.  In theses problems, the vocabulary is very large and predicting the correct labels (word in between or surrounding word depending on cbow or skip-gram) is done by computing the cosine distance with all internal vectors.

Comment: Well, I didn't think of this approach, I will give it a try in the future, but it still doesn't solve my problem :/.